# I am having error #1064 while creating trigger

Tags: mysql

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''

Here is my Trigger Statement

```
CREATE TRIGGER teq_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO rpt_process(

last_update,
updater,
table_id
)
VALUES (
NEW.last_updated, NEW.updater, NEW.iddev_est_reqs
);
```

please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Append `END;` keyword at the end of the trigger after insert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap it with;

```
DELIMITER //


END; //

DELIMITER ;
```